# How to automatically log in after sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, login

I want to make Win 7 to automatically log in into my account (the only one) after Sleep.
At start up it automatically logs in, but not after Sleep.

The 'Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer' option is unchecked: [image]

Comment: There might be an option in power settings "Ask for password after return from sleep". Under XP it's under the "advanced" tab

Comment: @Kwaio I think you might want to turn this into a full answer.

Comment: @Suma: I have no win7 here to make sure it is actually in this option menu and it actually works... that's why I prefered to comment.

Comment: @Kwaio It does work in Windows 7 also :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This option resides in the Power managment options. Here is how to find it :

Go to Control Panel, locate the "Power Settings" and double-click.
There you should find an "Advanced" tab where you will see a checkbox "Ask for a password after waking up from sleep" or similar.

Check it, save, and you should be set.

Comment: Thanks. +1 and Accepted. Enjoy your new reputation score :)

Comment: As it is a pretty security-related parameter it is logical to require Administrator rights to change it. Ask your local admin.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the chosen answer to work for me, but I did manage to solve it another way for my windows 7...

Start->Control Panel->Hardware and Sound->Power Options->Choose what the power button does(on the left panel)->Don't require a password(on the bottom, check this).